# Перестает работать autocomplete после переоткрытия JqueryUI - Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Собственно первый раз автозаполнение работает. Когда открываю диалоговое окно второй раз то автозаполнение уже не работает.

```
        var create_product = function () {
            isEdit = false;
            $(".dialog_create_product").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 800,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {},
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $( ".getInputComponent" ).autocomplete({
                        source: ['1','2','3'],
                    });
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("destroy")
                },
                beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                    closeDialog();
                }
            });
        };
```

html

```
  <div class="divInput"align="center">
        <input class = "getInputComponent" placeholder="название компонента" type="text" maxlength="50"><button class="addComponent" >Добавить компонент</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: как бы код посмотреть?, иначе ответом на ваш вопрос может быть только "видимо у вас что то не работает"

Comment: Сейчас попробою подрезать лишнее.

Comment: попробуйте написать автокомплит в хендлере `$(".dialog_create_product").on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {$( ".getInputComponent" ).autocomplete({source: ['1','2','3']});} );` а не в конструкторе как у вас, и отпишите результат

Comment: Может лучше так? `$(document).on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {$( ".getInputComponent" ).autocomplete({source: ['1','2','3']});} );` все равно срабатывает только единожды. C `$(".dialog_create_product").on` вообще не работает